# How to center 2 floating action buttons with labels on bottom (in flutter)?

Tags: flutter

Trying to do something like this in Flutter (I'm totally beginner), I don't get how to nest some widgets... I've tried to put a Row() for floating action buttons and another Row for labels but they aren't aligned centered like the image. Should I use GridView instead? thanks!

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, but instead of use two rows use only one [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) but with two [Columns](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) inside it, also with a row you can determine the position for each child according to the `mainAxisAlignment` and the `crossAxisAlignment`, for example to center the content use `MainAxisAlignment.center` as follows:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        Text(
          "Test"
        )

      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 16.0),
    Column(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        Text(
          "Test"
        )

      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

If you want to see a little more about layouts in Flutter you can check the [Building layouts](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial) tutorial section in the documentation.

Comment: oh I was close! haha... thanks sir, this worked like a charm!